# Best way to create dynamic content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Does it matter if I create the element and set the element attributes programmatically as in snippet 1 verses writing out the innerHTML as in snippet 2? What about using a templating library as suggested in one of the answers?

**snippet 1**

```
var link_element,
    image_element;

// create image element

image_element = $A.createElement('img');
image_element.className = "bookmark_image";
image_element.name = "bo_im";
image_element.src = bookmark_object.favicon;

// create link element

link_element = $A.createElement('a');
link_element.innerHTML = bookmark_object.title;
link_element.href = bookmark_object.url;
link_element.name = "bookmark_link";
link_element.className = "bookmark_link";
link_element.target = "_blank";

// append now
```

**snippet 2**

```
'<img name="bo_im class="bookmark_image" src="' + val.favicon + '">' +
'<a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="bookmark_link" href = "' + val.url + '" id="' + val.id + '">' + val.title + '</a>' +

// set to innerHTML now
```

Comment: If you find the second method "much easier" and "would like to use" it, why not just go with the second method?  It's shorter, it's more intuitive, and you want to do it!  If there are particular doubts you have about the second method, mentioning them would make this a more useful question.

Comment: You could write snippet 1 much neater and shorter. For example setting attributes can(should) be done with a (global) helper function that can set a bunch in a loop. `helpers.setAttr({name:'foo', className: 'bar', src: someSrcVar})`. jQuery has this option built in as well e.e. `$('<img>', {src:'./'})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good (IMO) solution to this problem is to use some sort of template library. One popular option would be [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), which has libraries for many languages [including JavaScript](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

The template approach consists of writing your HTML with placeholders in, e.g., a `<script>` tag:

```
<!-- very simple example -->
<script id="bookmark-template" type="text/html">
    <img name="bo_im" class="bookmark_image" src="{{favicon}}">
    <a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="bookmark_link" href="{{url}}" id="{{id}}">
        {{title}}
    </a>
</script>
```

Then when it comes time to render your dynamic content, you use the template and provide data to populate it accordingly:

```
var template = document.getElementById("bookmark-template").textContent;
var html = Mustache.render(template, bookmark_object);
```

To illustrate this more clearly, [here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bu5Av/2/) demonstrating this approach (including the benefit of escaping).

There are at least a couple of benefits to doing things this way:

1. Using a template lets you *actually* write HTML—with indentation, formatting, etc., to make it as readable as possible—rather than just "almost just copy it over", as you say in your question. You don't need to write one big string, or concatenate a bunch of strings with `+`, or use `+` at all for that matter.
2. A good templating library will properly escape your HTML for you.

To me, those benefits along are enough. You may feel differently.

Comment: I added a couple of benefits to the answer, along with a jsFiddle showing rather than telling. I don't know exactly what you mean by "writing html in javascript" (to me, your second approach of writing out an HTML string in JavaScript sounds more like that); but I don't think I'd characterize it that way. Take a look at the jsFiddle and let me know if you dislike this approach, and why. I'd be curious to know.

Comment: As a general rule, don't mix. Don't put markup(html) inside JavaScript because it will make your code harder to maintain.

Comment: @pure_code.mom: You could use a `div` tag, but then it would display. You'd then want to add `style: "display: none;"` (or use some equivalent approach) to ensure the template itself doesn't show on the page. Using a `script` tag is just a convention. Notice that the `type` attribute is set to "text/html" as opposed to "text/javascript".

Comment: Using the script tag is not just a convention. An advantage of using script tag with type template or similar is to make sure anything with a src attribute(images, iframes) won't get loaded when they are not yet required. There is a draft on a new template tag that will also do this afaik. But, not backwards compatible... the script tag is.

Comment: @Rene - isn't the actual text content with in the tags parsed differently as well?

Comment: @pure_code.mom: Yes, I think that's actually Rene's point; i.e., if you put the text inside a `<div>` tag, it's parsed *as HTML* and inserted into the DOM (which means images are loaded, for example). Using a `<script>` tag treats the content as raw text. Another (admittedly bizarre) option might be to use a `<textarea>`.

Comment: @pure_code.mom: If you're concerned that a `<script>` tag is necessarily going to be "executed" by the JavaScript engine, don't be. Setting the `type` attribute to "text/html" prevents execution. You can see for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/APBWL/

Answer (score 1):

**snippet 2** drops any dynamically added events, see the code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qnk9J/):

```
<div id="source">
  <div>item with click event</div>
</div>

<div id="target">
</div>

<script>
  var source = document.getElementById("source");
  var target = document.getElementById("target");
  source.children[0].onclick = alert.bind(null,"test");
  target.innerHTML = source.innerHTML; // onclick event is not copied
</script>
```

If you don't use dynamic events on created elements, stay with **snippet 1**: due to the "feature" mentioned above, it [seems to be faster](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html).

Comment: This just is not true.  Just tested this out and I can pull the element just fine when using snippet 2.

Comment: @pure_code.mom you were right: I used to work with dynamically created events and jumped into quick conclusion that the innerHTML is not parsed at all. Only those events are dropped, see my updated answer. And thank you for enlighten me!