# Dynamic content instead of constant reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On our online fashion store http://www.showstyle.lu I am the webmaster trying to improve the user experience perspective. I finally managed to use a toggle tool for our filters (click on any category: e.g. Homme) as you can see if you click on Couleurs/Tailles etc all the filters appear (they used to be displayed permanently which didn't look aesthethic).

Now, the issue is upon selection of filters the page is then reloaded with a new url to filter the products. Each time the filters then toggle back up of course and it's redundant to have to reclick each one and see what filter's one chose.

Is there a way I can either make the center content container refresh like php where the rest of the site remains static? Or otherwise can I at least force the toggle to remain open if the url has "%filter%*****" in it ?

We are using a ecommerce platform called SEOshop so I don't have access to every script/index page on the website but I have access to a large part.

The filters work on generation from backend so in the html code the placeholders are simply:

```
 {% for filter in collection.filters.custom %} <a class="filtertitle" href="javascript:;">
    <p>{{ filter.title }}</p>
    </a> 
    {% for value in filter.values %}
        <div class="filterbox2">
              <div class="sidebar-filter-item clearfix">
                <input id="filter_{{ value.id }}" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="{{ value.id }}" {% if value.active %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
                <label for="filter_{{ value.id }}">{{ value.title }}{% if not value.active and value.has_count %} <span>({{ value.count }})</span>{% endif %}</label>
              </div>
        </div> 
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
    </div>
```

Another topic, is it possible to have the toggle open a popup instead? Something to look like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5636466/showstyle/mockup_filters.png

Thanks for any help, I will continue my research and post my attempts/anything I find :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create dynamic content using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799766/best-way-to-create-dynamic-content-using-javascript)

Comment: Change of question, would it be possible that upon each reload the filters are all shown IF one is selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload only a specific part of the website then there is no way to do it only with php. What you are trying to do will require ajax requests to load the data without reloading the page and javascript to determine where it should be displayed (I would recommend looking into a framework like angular for that). I don't know anything about your site backend but I'm guessing this is not a trivial change and will require you to learn about such things.

Comment: Ah yes, I've used plenty ajax in the past, can't believed slipped my mind! I'll see what I find, so there are no JS workarounds because I feel any high developpment workload might not be possible with my limited access to the websites architecture

Comment: As far as i can tell your php server is rendering the page with the set parameters and sending it to the browser. If you can't change that behavior then you would need to extract the part of the website you want to change from the ajax response and then you can substitute it with the one that is displayed. It would probably be possible with a bit of jQuery, but this is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Change of question, would it be possible that upon each reload the filters are all shown IF one is selected?